Retopology CLO3D Garments
For an animation, I need to reptopologise my garment that I made in CLO3D. Previously I did do it by myself as well as Instant Meshes, but is there any other way how to quickly apply retopology for CLO3D garments. I tried the RetopoPlanes add-on, which doesn’t work for Clo3D…
Besides this it seems that for garments once you have applied the retopology, that I can only be done for obj/fbx (without motion). Is there any way that it can be applied to an alembic or moving garment?
Please let me know if you think of any solution.
